# Как лучше реализовать тест на JavaScript для проверки знания английскому языку

Tags: javascript

```js
let test = document.querySelector('#test');

let questions = [



    {
        text: 'Я программист',
        right: 'I',
        variant: 'AM',
        variant2: 'PROGRAMMER'
    },

];


for (let question of questions) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    test.appendChild(div);

    let otvet = document.createElement('div');
    test.appendChild(otvet);
    otvet.classList.add('otvet');
    div.classList.add('otvet');

    let otvets = document.createElement('div');
    test.appendChild(otvets);
    otvets.classList.add('otvet');
    div.classList.add('otvet');

    let div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.textContent = question.right;
    otvet.appendChild(div1);
    div1.classList.add('otvet');

    let div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.textContent = question.variant;
    otvet.appendChild(div2);
    div2.classList.add('otvet');

    let div3 = document.createElement('div');
    div3.textContent = question.variant2;
    otvet.appendChild(div3);
    div3.classList.add('otvet');
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = question.text;
    div.appendChild(p);

    

    function insert(elem, word) {

        let start = elem.selectionStart;
        elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, start) + word +
            elem.value.substring(elem.selectionEnd, elem.value.length)
        elem.focus();
        elem.setSelectionRange(start, start + word.length)
    }


    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.dataset.right = question.right;
    let input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.dataset.variant2 = question.variant2;




    let input3 = document.createElement('input');
    input3.dataset.variant = question.variant;

    div1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insert(input, div1.textContent = question.right)
        otvet.removeChild(div1);
        otvets.appendChild(input);
    });
    div2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insert(input2, div2.textContent = question.variant)
        otvet.removeChild(div2);
        otvets.appendChild(input2);
    });
    div3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insert(input3, div3.textContent = question.variant2)
        otvet.removeChild(div3);
        otvets.appendChild(input3);
    });
}

let button = document.querySelector('#button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#test input');

    for (let input of inputs) {
        input.classList.remove('correct');
        input.classList.remove('incorrect');

        if (input.value == input.dataset.right


        ) {
            input.classList.add('correct');

        } else if (input.value == input.dataset.variant) {
            input.classList.add('correct');
        } else {
            input.classList.add('incorrect');
        }

    }


})
```

```css
#test div {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#button {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

input {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.input2{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.otvet{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   border: 2px solid; 
}
.correct {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.incorrect {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    


    <title>Россия</title>
</head>
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="button">Проверить</button>
<script src='./index.js'></script>
    </body>
```

Всем доброго вечера. Я начал делать маленькое приложение для изучения английского языка.
Если кратко это должно работать так:
Пользователю предлагается составить несколько английских предложений,
предложения выбираются в рандомном порядке.
Для начала я хотел бы сделать проверку на правильность порядка слов в предложение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на правильность результатов по коду.
Буду рад любой помощи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добрый вечерочек, советую использовать библиотеку jquery, а именно sortable, droppable, draggable для 2 - 3 секции.
Как организовать логику скрипта не подскажу вариантов очень много, думайте сами или задавайте вопрос конкретнее.

Comment: Помощи в каком виде вы ожидаете? Ну то есть подсказку по коду или подсказку по алгоритму или подсказку в том, как сравнить правильность или что использовать для перемещения объектов и использование sort, drag, drop и т.д.? То есть что хотя бы примерно вас смущает сейчас и интересует? А то не совсем ясно

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Меня больше интересует как сравнить правильность ответов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечаю на свой вопрос. Я все таки реализовал, то что хотел. Код я представляю в простом варианте.
**Что я сделал**
Я сделал мини-тест  на проверку знаний английского языка. Представлено выражение на русском языке `Я программист` . Ниже блок с кнопками, нажимая на них-выставляем слова в нужном порядке слова. Далее нажимая на кнопку 'проверка'- происходит проверка на правильность выражения, если слово не правильно- оно подсвечивается красной рамкой.

```js
const questionsRus = ["Я", "программист"]
const questions = ["I'm", "a", "programmer"];
const answers = [];

const text1 = document.querySelector('.vopros-text1');
const text2 = document.querySelector('.vopros-text2');
const text3 = document.querySelector('.vopros-text3');
const text4 = document.querySelector('.otvet-text');
const text5 = document.querySelector('.otvet-text5');
const text6 = document.querySelector('.otvet-text6');
const buttonProverka = document.querySelector('.button__proverka');
const otvet = document.querySelector('.otvet-variant');

const buttonText1 = document.querySelector('.text4');
const buttonText2 = document.querySelector('.text5');
const buttonText3 = document.querySelector('.text6');




//текст кнопок
const textVariant1 = buttonText1.textContent = "programmer";
const textVariant2 = buttonText2.textContent = "a";
const textVariant3 = buttonText3.textContent = "I'm";

const pushed1 = () => {
    let res = answers.push(textVariant1);
    text4.textContent = textVariant1;
    otvet.appendChild(text4);
    return res;
}


const pushed2 = () => {
    let res = answers.push(textVariant2);
    text5.textContent = textVariant2;
    otvet.appendChild(text5);
    return res;
}

const pushed3 = () => {
    let res = answers.push(textVariant3);
    text6.textContent = textVariant3;
    otvet.appendChild(text6);
    return res;
}


buttonText1.addEventListener("click", pushed1);
buttonText2.addEventListener("click", pushed2);
buttonText3.addEventListener("click", pushed3);


text1.textContent = questionsRus[0];
text2.textContent = questionsRus[1];
text3.textContent = questionsRus[2];




const checkAnswers = (a, b) => {
    return a.map((item, idx) => item === b[idx]);
}
buttonProverka.addEventListener("click", proverka);



function proverka() {
    let res = checkAnswers(answers, questions);

    if (res[0] === false) {
        text4.classList.add('border-red');
    } else {
        text4.classList.add('border-green')
    };

    if (res[1] === false) {
        text5.classList.add('border-red');
    } else {
        text5.classList.add('border-green')
    };
    if (res[2] === false) {
        text6.classList.add('border-red')
    } else {
        text6.classList.add('border-green')
    };
 
   }
```

```css
.vopros{
    display:flex;
    margin:10px;
    }
    .otvet{
        display:flex;   
    }
    .border-red{
        border:solid 1px red;
    }
    .border-green{
        border:solid 1px green;
    }

    .otvet-variant{
        display:flex;   
    }
    .otvet-text{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .otvet-text5{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .otvet-text6{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .vopros-text1{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .vopros-text2{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vopros">
    <p class="vopros-text1"></p>
    <p class="vopros-text2"></p>
    <p class="vopros-text3"></p>
</div>
<div class="otvet-variant">
    <p class="otvet-text"></p>
    <p class="otvet-text5"></p>
    <p class="otvet-text6 "></p>
</div>

<div class="otvet">
    <button class="text4"></button>
    <button class="text5"></button>
    <button class="text6"></button>
</div>
<button class="button__proverka">Проверить</button>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```